# Sumar arreglo obteniendo los datos mediante un fichero .txt

Tags: java, java-ee

Buena tarde amigos les comento, estoy con un proyecto Java EJB, el cual es simular un banco usando una bd tipo txt, la cual contiene: Cuenta/Clave / Saldo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar me muestra las cuentas, me pide cuenta y clave, y me muestra el saldo de la cuenta: asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que valida la sesion:

```
@Override
public String validarSesion(String n_cuenta, String clave) {
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String ver_cuentas="";

    try {
       // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
       // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
       archivo = new File ("C:/Users/david/Desktop/prybanco/bd.txt");
       fr = new FileReader (archivo);
       br = new BufferedReader(fr);          

       // Lectura del fichero
       String linea;
       while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] parts = linea.split("\\s+");
            if(n_cuenta.equals(parts[0]) && clave.equals(parts[1])){
                ver_cuentas = parts[0]+"    "+parts[1]+"    "+parts[2];  



            }
            //ver_cuentas+=linea+"\n";
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
       // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
       // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
       // una excepcion.
       try{                    
          if( null != fr ){   
             fr.close();     
          }                  
       }catch (Exception e2){ 
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    return ver_cuentas;
}
```

Necesito es, una vez se valide la cuenta, me de la opción de retirar y de consignar a otras cuenta, por lo cual se emplearia un switch, pero lo que no tengo conocimiento es en como escribir esto en el txt, osea que me modifique el saldo de la cuenta.

Nota: El metodo esta en la enterprise Aplication ejb. Se crea un Enterprise application client(main), donde se llama el metodo.

gracias

Comment: Es que estás intentando usar un archivo texto para simular una base de datos. Si lo quieres hacer así requieres leer todo el archivo y generar un arreglo de cuentas. Luego hacer los cambios a las cuentas y volver a crear ese archivo texto con todas las cuentas actualizadas.

Comment: Si exacto, eso estoy haciendo en el metodo de cargar datos y validar, pero como hago para editar y refrescar estas cuentas?

Comment: Necesitas un java.io.FileWriter para escribir en el archivo. Y leer todas las cuentas cada ver que quieras actualizar el archivo y volver a grabarlas todas en el mismo formato en el que las lees.

Answer (score 0):

No me animaría a intentar implementar una base de datos en un archivo texto, pero si fuera para una tarea rápida lo haría con la siguiente clase Cuenta.  Ahora que le faltan validaciones pero solo para que veas una opción.

```
public class Cuenta {

private int numero;
private String clave;
private long saldo;


/**
 * Construimos la cuenta con un String que leemos del archivo
*/    
public Cuenta(String linea) {
    String[] parts = linea.split("\\s+");
    numero = new Integer(parts[0].trim());
    clave = parts[1];
    saldo = new Long(parts[2].trim());
}

/**
 * Escribimos una cuenta en una línea al writer o escritor
 * @param writer
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void escribe(BufferedWriter escritor) throws IOException {
    String linea = numero+" "+clave+" "+saldo;
    escritor.write(linea);
    escritor.newLine();
}
/**
 * Aquí guardamos todas las cuentas a un archivo.
 * @param cuentas
 * @param archivo
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void guarda(Cuenta[] cuentas, String archivo) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter escritora = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));) {
        for (Cuenta cuenta : cuentas) {
            cuenta.escribe(escritora);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Con este método cargamos todas las cuentas
 * @param archivo
 * @return
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static Cuenta[] carga(String archivo) throws IOException {
    java.util.ArrayList<Cuenta> lista = new java.util.ArrayList();
    try (BufferedReader lectora = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));) {
        String linea;
        while((linea = lectora.readLine())!=null){
            lista.add(new Cuenta(linea));
        }
    }
    Cuenta[] cuentas = new Cuenta[lista.size()];
    lista.toArray(cuentas);
    return cuentas;        
}



}
```

Espero te sirva como idea, y si tienes duda de algo en esto me avisas. Saludos